# Complex Event Processing with C#

Tags: c#, .net

Can you suggest me a possible way to get started with CEP in C# ?

By what I mean when I say, get started:

- A good book talking about CEP and C#
- A library which deals event clouds
- Some sample codes using the library
- Some good quality codes in general to get a possible feel of the problems
- Good blogs

Anything else you might feel necessary to add for someone getting started in CEP and C# will be helpful.

Thanks
Soham

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no such book. Yet. There is an upcoming book in the next couple of weeks from Manning called [Event Processing in Action](http://www.manning.com/etzion/), it is a 'must read'.

For C#, the obvious choice is StreamInsight from Microsoft. There's a collection of useful links here: [StreamInsight Info](http://rulecore.com/CEPblog/?p=539)

Apart from that, there's StreamBase, Oracle CEP Server, ruleCore CEP Server and the open source Esper. Most (not Esper) vendors take a language neutral approach so you would not need to care in which language the CEP product uses when sending events into it.

Comment: You the man! I was actually going through Esper's page and was finding it a bit puzzling to find it didnt take a language neutral approach. Thanks for the StreamInsight link.
Thanks for Manning as well!

Comment: If you are thinking of using Esper for commercial use, beware - Esper is GPL (*not* LGPL) :(

Answer (score 1):

From your question it sounds as you would like to do CEP programming. Many tools have a higher form of abstraction. For example StreamBase have a nice GUI where you select different functions from a palette of icons and then connect them in order to make it do what you like. 
The ruleCore CEP Server has a high level declarative language where you specify the CEP rules using XML. Both these approaches are in my view not programming.

Esper and StreamInsight are good examples of putting CEP functionality in there that can be reached from your normal programming language. So if programming is what you like to do, StreamInsight is a good candidate.

Comment: Hmm... thanks. Does StreamInsight also require knowing/learning XML. I am afraid I am not that good at it

Comment: @Soham - No - you do not have to know XML to use StreamInsight. You write high level LINQ, and its compiled into XML in the background, which is then JIT compiled into IL. Its all transparent, and it just works.

Answer (score 0):

No, StreamInsight does not require learning XML. But even if it would, basic XML is *very* easy to learn...